# Changing background image of SimpleDraweeView in Fresco programmatically

Tags: fresco

I need to change the background color of the SimpleDraweeView, is there any functions I could use to do this? SetBackgroundColor ignores the circular shape.

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                        android:id="@+id/message_status_image"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/medium_icon"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/medium_icon"
                        fresco:backgroundImage="@color/grey"
                        fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/ic_linked_white"
                        fresco:roundAsCircle="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing background image dynamically is not supported at the moment. What you can do as a workaround is build a `DraweeHierarchy` programmatically as explained in the [documentation](http://frescolib.org/docs/using-drawees-code.html), and set a custom Drawable for the background. Keep a reference to that drawable so that you can access it later on.

Instead of a custom drawable, you can simply use the existing `RoundedColorDrawable` and when you need to change the color you just have to do `mBackgroundDrawable.setColor(color)`.